# Evaluating the derivative of $\large \;e^{e^x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the derivative of $\,e^x\,$ is $\,e^x$.

But how do I evaluate $\dfrac{d}{dx}{\large\left(e^{e^x}\right)}\,$?

Comment: Chain rule...${}$.

Comment: You need to use the chain rule.

Comment: What does this have to do with integration?

Comment: Its related to Bell numbers I think so.

Comment: It's funny that I asked the same question from my students last week.

Answer (score 26):

To differentiate $\large e^{e^x},\,$ we use the [**chain rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

$$\large \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{f(x)}\right) = f'(x)\cdot e^{f(x)}$$

Here, we have that $e^{f(x)} = e^{e^x}$, so $f(x) = e^x$.

Thus $f'(x) = e^x,\,$ as you know. That gives us:

$$\large \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{(e^x)}\right) = \underbrace{e^x}_{f'(x)}\cdot\,\underbrace{e^{(e^x)}}_{e^{f(x)}}$$

Comment: ${+1}{}{}{}$ TU!

Comment: All that large mathematics is ugly, but it is sadly true that without it, the exponents tend to get too small on screen. Is it generally better in such a case to switch notation, to $\exp e^x$, or is it confusing to mix those?

Comment: I've debated that @dfeuer. In general $\exp e^x$ would be the route *I* would go, in my own work. But in a situation like this, where the OP seems to clearly be confused, I'm afraid that to do so would be confusing to him/her. Thanks for the edit, btw.

Answer (score 19):

**Hint**:   $$(e^u) '=u 'e^u$$

> $$(e^{e^x}) '=e^xe^{e^x}$$

Comment: how do you add the spoiler thing?

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos You use `>!`

Comment: $\large{\color{red}{+1}}$ for the spoiler trick!

Comment: @Ali: thx dear ali

Comment: Hit the "edit" button to see how it was done.  (Then be sure to "cancel" rather than actually editing.)

Answer (score 14):

take $u=e^x$ and $y = e^u$

> $$ \large {y' = u'e^u = e^x e^{e^x}}$$

Answer (score 8):

Hint:  Apply the chain rule.  You would get $\frac d{dx}e^{e^x}=e^{x+e^x}$

Answer (score 7):

It's the derivative of a function of function.
$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. So:
$\frac{d}{dx}\exp(\exp(x))=\exp(x)\exp(\exp(x))$

Answer (score 6):

Here's another method: for any positive function $f$, its derivative equals the function $f$ times its logarithmic derivative. In our case $f(x)=e^{e^x}$, so its logarithm, $e^x$, has derivative $e^x$.